# Inputing Text with spaces closes the program instantly

Tags: c++

When inputing the text like "School" it reads and outputs how many vowels are in the text but whenever inputing "School School" it instantly closes when pressing enter.
Been trying to see the problem for multiple lessons and cant seem to find it.
    #pragma hdrstop
    #pragma argsused

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <iomanip>

// Autors : Deivids Roberts Saulite
/* Masīvs no N elemmntiem satur anglu alfabēta burtus. Noteikt cik masiva
 ir patskanu, kas atrodas masīva elementos ar para numuriem */
int main() {
    char teikums[150]; // Masiva lielums
    int i, blank, patsk;
    char yesno;
    do {
        system("cls");
        patsk = blank = 0;

        cout << "Ievadi teikumu:";
        cin >> teikums;
        cout << "Izmantotie Patskani:";
        for (i = 0; teikums[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (teikums[i] == 'a' || teikums[i] == 'e' || teikums[i] == 'o' ||
                teikums[i] == 'o' || teikums[i] == 'u' || teikums[i] == 'A' ||
                teikums[i] == 'E' || teikums[i] == 'I' || teikums[i] == 'O' ||
                teikums[i] == 'U') {
                ++patsk;
                cout << " " << teikums[i];
            }
        }


        cout << "\nPatskanu Skaits: " << patsk;

        cout << ("\nVai velaties atkartot(Y/cits):");
        // prasa lietotajam vai velas atkartot
        cin >> yesno;
        if (yesno == 'y' || yesno == 'Y') {
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while (tolower(yesno) != 'n');
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `cin >>` uses white spaces to delimit the input. You read one string, and there are still stuff left in the buffer, so your hack of waiting on `yesno` fails. Use `std::getline` instead

Answer (score 0):

The second time you read in input, you check if it's a 'y' and if not, you return out of the subroutine. Which since it's main, exits your program.